# Use escape character in Ballerina regex

Tags: regex, ballerina

```
public function main() {
    boolean matches = regex:matches("ABCdef", "^(?!\s*$).+");
}
```

In the above code snippet, we have used a regex with an escape character.
When compiling the code, a compile error is thrown as shown below.

```
invalid escape sequence '\s'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

In order to escapse we have to use `\\` instead of `\`.

Therefore the correct code is,

```
import ballerina/regex;

public function main() {
    boolean matches = regex:matches("ABCdef","^(?!\\s*$).+");
}
```

Please check the Ballerina regex document https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/regex/1.3.0#matches for more details.

Comment: It was always better to use the new ballerina regexp library to pattern matching and other stuff. It supports a wider grammar along with use regexp functions where they help to search and manipulate strings. You can find the link from [here](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.regexp/0.0.0).